# What happens when the Beholder beholds a Drunk Seer who was drunk that night?

Tags: werewolv.es

What happens when the Beholder beholds a Drunk Seer who was drunk that night? Does he see what they beheld before they blacked out, or does he just see that they were drunk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As lore dictates, the Drunk seer checks their target before blacking out and inevitably forgetting what the result of their check was. The same does NOT apply to the Beholder because guess what? THEY WEREN'T DRUNK! So the Beholder can actually find out what the Drunk seer's report is on the night that they get drunk.