# What does a Beholder see if they behold a Drunk Seer who gets drunk?

Tags: werewolv.es

Mechanically, the Beholder takes a copy of their target's role (with some small exceptions, e.g. Bloodhound -> Seer) and then uses that copy to visit their target's target.

On any given night, the Drunk Seer has a certain chance to get drunk and forget their check. So... Does the beholder copy the Drunk Seer role? If so, do they get drunk if (and only if) the Drunk Seer gets drunk, or is the drunkenness independent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when the Beholder beholds a Drunk Seer who was drunk that night?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362150/what-happens-when-the-beholder-beholds-a-drunk-seer-who-was-drunk-that-night)